# "Laurent phenomenon"?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, polynomials, recurrences

Define the recurrence
\begin{align*}
n(2n+x-3)u_n(x)
&=2(2n+x-2)(4n^2+4nx-8n-3x+3)u_{n-1}(x) \\
&-4(n+x-2)(2n-3)(2n+2x-3)(2n+x-1)u_{n-2}(x)
\end{align*}
with initial conditions $u_0(x)=0$ and $u_1(x)=x+1$.

The subject of ["Laurent phenomenon"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0104241.pdf) was motivated by [Somos sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somos_sequence). In the same spirit, I ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is it true that each $u_n(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$? In fact, with positive integer coefficients.

**EXAMPLES.** $u_2(x)=5x^2 + 13x + 6$ and $u_3(x)=22x^3 + 114x^2 + 164x + 60$ and
\begin{align*}
u_4(x)&=93x^4 + 814x^3 + 2367x^2 + 2606x + 840 \\
u_5(x)&=386x^5 + 5140x^4 + 25030x^3 + 54500x^2 + 51024x + 15120.
\end{align*}

Comment: Are you mixing $a$'s and $x$'s?

Comment: @SamHopkins: there were typos. Thanks!

Comment: Is it a Somos sequence?

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov: I don't think it is.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In fact,
$$
u_n(x) = 
{2}^{n-1}\prod _{k=0}^{n-1}(2x+2k+1)
-{2\,n-1\choose n-1}\prod _{k=0}^{n-1}(x+k) ,
\tag1$$
which is a polynomial with integer coefficients.

P.S. the proof rests on a routine verification that (1) satisfies the given recurrence relation and initial conditions.

Comment: Interesting. How did you find this?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan I guess this gave some clues: http://oeis.org/search?q=5%2C22%2C93%2C386&language=english&go=Search

Comment: Is $u_n(x)/(x+n)$ always irreducible ? I have verified it numerically up to $n=170$.

Comment: @CHUAKS: I agree.